# Binary tree 'smart' search function in c

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need a function for 'smart' search which will  return number of elements in binary tree which are greater then given parameter but wont go through all nodes.

For example, if i want to find number of elements which are greater than 16 it wont look for them in left node of 15 and so on.

```
                    20
                   /   \
                  15   21
                 /  \    \
                5  17    28
               / \      / \
              1   8   24  30
                     / \
                    23  26
```

I made a function which go through all nodes and it looks like this:

```
void search(node* p, int k, int* num)
{
     if(p)
     {
         search(p->left, k, num);
         if(p->info > k)
             (*num)++;
         search(p->right,k, num);         
     }           
}
```

Comment: "I need a function..." sounds like homework.

Comment: `it wont look for them in left node of 15`, how about that `17`??

Comment: it's not a homework, i edited question with my code. 17 is right of 15

Comment: Yes, I see your edit. Good so far. But you need to be more specific. Where are your problems?

Comment: i also tried to ask if p->info is less then k before search(p->left...) and if it is then don't go left, go right, also for the right, and also i multiplied all nodes i want through by -1 just to see what i did on printing. But it doesn't work

Comment: And problem in function in my question is because it goes through all nodes, and i want it to be as fast as possible

Comment: @HowChen: that's the *right* node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple, really.

if the current node is <= k, don't go left, because nothing in the left sub-tree will be > k.
You still have to go right, though.

```
if (p->info > k) {
    (*num)++;
    search(p->left, k, num);
}
search(p->right, k, num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Literary do what you said.

Modify your algorithm not to check the left child if the value at node <= k.

Note: you can get a lot better performance if you modify your tree to store in each node the number of children (the sum, recursively).

Answer (score 0):

Create another field in the `tree_node` which stores the `in order` number of that node. `Inorder number` means the rank of the node when the tree is traversed in `inorder` fashion. For your example, it looks as follows:

```
                 6
                / \
               4   7
              / \   \
             2   5   11
            / \     / \
           1   3   9   12
                  / \
                 8  10
```

Now, given the number, go to that node, which is just greater than the given one. You also need to maintain a total count of the nodes in the tree so far.

The answer will be `Total nodes - Current_Nodes_Rank + 1`.

It can literally be done in `O(logN)` time, at an expense of `O(N)` memory. Also remember that the tree is highly sensitive to updates. You need an additional `O(N)` time to update the `rank` of each node when a new node is added to the tree.

For example, given the number is `16`. First you see, `20(>16)`. So, go left to find a more nearer one. We have `15`. But its less than `16`. Go right to find a nearer one. We have `17`. Since this is a valid one, and it doesn't have any more childs, stop here.

See the `inorder rank` of `17`. So the answer is `12-5+1 = 8`.

Hope this helps.